# Embedding image in Outlook 2013

Tags: html, image, email, outlook, inline

I need to be able to send an image in the signature line through HTML files. 
However, it can not come from a webserver because the receiver of the mail will have a delay while downloading the image from the net.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're using Microsoft Outlook from your tags, so I suggest to do the following:

Create the signature in Microsoft Word. Then save as:

- HTML page - `html`
- Rich Text Document - `rtf`
- Plain Text Document - `txt`

Then you will have three files and a folder. Copy all that into your signature folder - found at

`[disk letter]/Users/[username]/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Signatures/`

They will now appear in Outlook, and the images should attach - but the receiver wont see them as attachments.

Comment: No, the default format in all latest versions of Outlook is HTML. You probably set it to RTF in Options |  Mail | Compose Messages in this format.

Comment: Your're right - I just checked - I put that without checking :/

Comment: When i just put <img src="example.png">, the receiver of my mail doesn't see the image.
The other computer is then looking for the file saved on mine

Comment: I've already set 'Send Pictures With Documents' to 1 (In the Registry)

Comment: @DieterLangie like I said - edit or build it in word. Outlook uses Word's html engine anyway, so how you see it in word is how you are going to see it in outlook.